# Como capturar imagens da webcam em OpenCV em Java?

Tags: java, vídeo, opencv, webcam

Olá, sou iniciante em opencv com java, e meu problema é o seguinte, quero capturar a imagem em tempo real da minha webcam e transmiti-la em uma JLabel, porém estou tem um problema ao executar o arquivo, o netbeans aponta o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J

estou usando a Função VideoCapture da biblioteca do opencv, abaixo o trecho do código:

```
private void BotaoStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                           
    Mat imageMat = new Mat(); // matriz de imagem //

    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
    capture.open(0); // abre dispositivo de video de índice 0 //

    // especifica altura e largura do video //
    capture.set(org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);
    capture.set(org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);

    BufferedImage image;

    capture.read(imageMat); //Captura o quadro
    image = this.matToBufferedImage(imageMat); //Converte para imageBuffer

    while(capture.isOpened()){
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        this.TelaImagem.setIcon(icon);
        this.TelaImagem.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(150);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }

}
```

essa é a função que converte o tipo Mat para BufferedImage:

```
public BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat matrix) {  
 int cols = matrix.cols();  
 int rows = matrix.rows();  
 int elemSize = (int)matrix.elemSize();  
 byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];  
 int type;  
 matrix.get(0, 0, data);  
 switch (matrix.channels()) {  
   case 1:  
     type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;  
     break;  
   case 3:  
     type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;  
     // bgr to rgb  
     byte b;  
     for(int i=0; i<data.length; i=i+3) {  
       b = data[i];  
       data[i] = data[i+2];  
       data[i+2] = b;  
     }  
     break;  
   default:  
     return null;  
 }  
 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cols, rows, type);  
 image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, cols, rows, data);  
 return image;
```

}

o erro aponta para a linha de declaração de Mat imageMat = new Mat(); , alguem saberia o que está ocasionando esse erro? desde já agradeço.

Comment: Depois de algumas horas descobri o problema da mensagem de erro, faltou colocar esta linha na classe principal:
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Porém o programa ainda está com problema, ao executar, e ao acionar o botao iniciar a imagem nao é gerada no jLabel e a janela trava. Alguem saberia como fazer funcionar? grato desde já.

Comment: Yuri, não faça novas perguntas nos comentários. Há pouca chance de alguém te ajudar. Já que conseguiu resolver essa por conta própria, apague essa pergunta (ou responda você mesmo) e abra uma nova pergunta com sua nova dúvida, ok?

Comment: aconteceu o mesmo erro comigo.
A única coisa que fiz foi tirar o cabo usb extensor da webcam e conectar a webcam sem o extensor. Ai executei o jFrame novamente e funcionou. Espero ter ajudado.